# How to Create a Modal

Tags: css, modal-dialog

I am new to this area and was trying to create a modal. I found this modal: http://drublic.github.io/css-modal/#howto
but could not understand what files to include in my webpage. I see there are a lot of different files (SCSS, CSS, and JS) and many others. 
What are the files I should include before writing the markup and getting started on this assignment?

Comment: why there are downvotes? I don't understand this community!

Comment: There are downvotes because you have not provided any code, which means the question is either extremely vague, or you're expecting a member to write the code for you, which is not what SO is about. Have a read here about creating good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think some of these questions should be left up, as there are many newcomers who don't know yet how to include files and where, hell, I still struggle sometimes when I 'steal' code from elsewhere:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap modals. They are flexible and required minimum functionality..

```
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Required CSS and JS files are available in **JsFiddle's External Resources** link

You can find more help and information from ***[Here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/)*** and below is a working example as well.

***[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/DTcHh/22941/)***